# IntelliJ Community Edition cannot run a simple Java class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I downloaded IntelliJ Community edition, and installed JDK 15 yesterday. I can select 'Debug' to execute a simple Java class, and see its results on Debug console. But I cannot select 'Run' to execute it. There is no messages indicate what is wrong.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a new `Run configuration` in order to run your program - to do so press `Alt+Shift+F10` and select `Edit configurations` (this is also explained [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html)).

Then, choose your `Main` class and configure your classpath if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I wonder without creating a new Run Configuration, why I can select  'Debug' to execute the code, but cannot use  'Run' to execute the code?

Comment: Because the run config is missing, hence my answer how to add a new one :) I cannot tell you why the run config is missing though.